# PHP Class: how to get a random value from an array without the result changing on refresh?

Tags: php

I'm trying to complete a simple task where I have an array with 5 values where I need to randomise many times and display the results on a page.

For example, my array could be `('color1','color2','color3','color4','color5')`.

I need to display, say 50 items on the page with randomised colours, the number of items may increase or decrease depending on other factor.

When an item have been assigned a color then it'll always be that color, instead of it changing everytime I refresh the page.

I'm currently using `array_rand` and it's randomizing the colours every time I refresh the page. `shuffle` seems to be giving me exactly the same colours on all items.

```
<?php
class Item{
    public $color;
    public $colorArray = array('#000','#fff','#0008b2','#0f9d00','#fff600');

    public function __construct() {
        $this->color = $this->pickColor($this->colorArray);
    } 

    public function pickColor($colors) {        
        $randNum = array_rand($colors);
        $this->color = $this->colorArray[$randNum];
        return $this->color;
    }
}
?>
```

Then on my index page I have:

```
<?php 
    $item = new Item();
    echo $item->color;
?>
```

Comment: Choose where you want to save your first randomized results (e.g. session, database, file-system, etc.). On page load check if you've already saved data. If so read it, otherwise shuffle your array assign items to desired dom objects and save them..

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect better on the issue

Comment: Do your items have any distinguishable features? Like, an id, name, etc. that would uniquely identify them?

Comment: @Jack nothing is set for this stage, ID, class or name will all be fine.

Comment: Then use id % count($colors) as the index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will make sense for you:

```
<?php
class Item{

    public $id;
    public $color;
    public $colorArray = array('#000','#fff','#0008b2','#0f9d00','#fff600');

    public function __construct($id) {

        $this->id = $id;

        if(!empty($_SESSION['element_' . $id])) {
            $this->color = $_SESSION['element_' . $id];
        }
        else {
            $this->color = $this->pickColor($this->colorArray);
        }
    }

    public function pickColor($colors) {        
        return $colors[rand(0, count($colors))];
    }
}
?>

<?php
$_SESSION['element_4'] = 'color of carrot';

for($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
    $temp = new Item($i);
    echo($temp->color . '<br/>');
}

die('Done');
?>
```

Test it by refreshing - element 4 will always have the same value: 'color of carrot'.

This piece of code is based on comments under your question.

---

UPDATE: I have added some ID to identify that this element's color was already set, so we can easily store it in session. If you don't provide any identification you will not be able to do it.

Also I think that colorArray and pickColor method should be static for this class in this case, but I will leave it to you.

Comment: thanks for your help, I've updated my question to reflect better on the issue - I realized it probably wasn't asked properly.